# Is there a db level limit in number of records returned in a query result (eg: in 'all' query) in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

This is just a theoretical question,  for example there are 1 billion records in a collection, and i want to query all the records in one go. Will the mongodb return all the records ?.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo db can easily handle billions of documents with maximum document size not more than 16mb.The maximum document size helps ensure that a single document cannot use excessive amount of RAM or, during transmission, excessive amount of bandwidth. To store documents larger than the maximum size, MongoDB provides the GridFS API.

If you have a production deployment of MongoDB with replica sets with or without lag, and you've sharded with right key so that distribution is even across the shards, you need not worry about the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB limits are documented [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/). There does not appear to be a limit on the number of documents in a collection, or in a query result set.